# How can I import CSV files into HIVE using an external schema (like Avro)?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, schema, avro

I am importing zipped csv-like log files (delimiter separated, without header) into HDFS and want to aggregate them using HIVE. However, I like the idea of separating a (declarative) schema from the aggregation query, as it is a clean way to track the schema history.

Is there a (direct) way to import csv files into HIVE using an external schema (like Avro)? If not, is there a better way in 2 steps to do so or can I only specify the file structure in HQL?

So far I tried to use both Avro and CSV serialization in HIVE without success.

My csv files `test.log.gz` look like this

```
val0|val1|val2||val3
val4|val5|val6||val7
```

I created an Avro schema `test.avsc`

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "test",
  "name": "TestFile",
  "fields": [
     { "name": "field0" , "type": "string", "doc": "Field 0" },
     { "name": "field1" , "type": "string", "doc": "Field 1" },
     { "name": "field2" , "type": "null", "doc": "N/A" },
     { "name": "field3" , "type": "string", "doc": "Field 3" }
  ]
}
```

The reason why I would like to do this, is that I could have a separate place for the (long) file specification including also description of the fields in a readable format.

#### Update 1:

I was also considering converting the CSV file to Avro format beforehand. However, I found that [this is also done via HIVE](https://dzone.com/articles/convert-csv-data-avro-data). Using the [Avro tools](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/) via the commandline works great for JSON but not for CSV.

Comment: have you tried the json serde ?

Comment: My log files are delimiter separated (CSV-like), so I don't know how JSON serde could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this using [`Apache Kite`](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.0.0/introduction-to-datasets.html), a good tutorial can be found on [kitesdk.org](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.0.0/introduction-to-datasets.html).

First, you need to create a Hive table from an Avro schema:

```
kite-dataset create sandwiches -s sandwich.avsc
```

Then you can import the csv data into the table.

```
kite-dataset csv-import sandwiches.csv sandwiches
```

This let's me declare and version schemas for my resources and import the csv files into Hive from the commandline.